# StreamExt::forward fails with error `expected integer, found enum `std::result::Result``

Tags: rust, future

I'm trying to connect a rust futures stream (repeat) to a sink (drain).
The first method works fine (check below), but the second one with `.forward` fails to compile (the error is shown inline). Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong?

```
use futures::stream::StreamExt;
use futures::sink::SinkExt;
use futures::executor;

fn main() {
    executor::block_on( async {
        // works
        let mut work = futures::stream::repeat(5);
        let mut drain = futures::sink::drain();
        match drain.send(work.next()).await {
            Ok(_r) => println!("Done"),
            Err(_e) => println!("Error"),
        };

        // works
        let res: Vec<i32> = futures::stream::repeat(5).take(3).collect::<Vec<i32>>().await;
        println!("{:?}", res);

        // doesn't work
        // futures::stream::repeat(5).forward(futures::sink::drain());
        //                            ^^^^^^^ expected integer, found enum `std::result::Result`
        //  error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<futures_util::stream::repeat::Repeat<{integer}> as futures_core::stream::Stream>::Item == std::result::Result<_, _>`

        // Fixed above with repeat(Ok(5)) but not repeat(5)
        match futures::stream::repeat(Ok(5)).take(3).forward(futures::sink::drain()).await {
            Ok(_r) => println!("Done"),
            Err(_e) => println!("Error"),
        };
    });
}
```

Relevant docs

- https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/stream/fn.repeat.html
- https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/sink/fn.drain.html
- https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.forward

Comment: You're right. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you wanted something a bit more like this?

```rust
use futures::stream::StreamExt;
use futures::sink::SinkExt;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // works
    let mut work = futures::stream::repeat(5);
    let mut drain = futures::sink::drain();
    match drain.send(work.next()).await {
        Ok(_r) => println!("Done"),
        Err(_e) => println!("Error"),
    };
    // doesn't work

    futures::stream::repeat(Ok(5)).forward(futures::sink::drain());
}
```

As the error (slightly confusingly) illustrates, the repeat call must take a `Result` argument in this case.

Comment: Indeed. Doesn't the error message make more sense to be reversed to `expected enum std::result::Result, found integer`?

Comment: @shadi I think error message with async are currently buggy.

Comment: I'm not sure it's /too/ terrible. It's the reverse of that which you may intuitively have thought based on my solution because it's failing to find a type that satisfies the `forward` function, rather than the `repeat` parameter. The `forward` function stipulates a `Result` type, hence the message. IIUC (which I probably don't at this point in my rust learning)